# Basic level Java program. Missing return statement exception

Tags: java, function, logic

I keep getting the error "Missing return statement" for my int chkCM(int n) function. Any thoughts? 
P.S The program is to check whether the entered number if a Composite Magic number or not.

Here's my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Composite_Magic{
    public static void main (String args[]){

    Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is a Composite Magic number or not");
    int n=s.nextInt();
    boolean isPrime=false;

        for(int i=2;i<=(n/2);i++)
            if(n%i==0)
                isPrime=true;

        if(isPrime==false){
            if(chkCM(n)==n)
              System.out.println("Composite Magic Number");
            else
              System.out.println("Not a Composite Magic Number");        
        }
    else
        System.out.println("Not a Composite number");
    }

    static int chkCM(int n){
    int sum=0;    

    while(n!=0){
        sum+=n%10;
        n/=10;
    }
    n=sum;

    if(sum%10!=sum)
        chkCM(sum);
    else
        return sum;        
    }
}
```

Comment: A good first step would be to indent your code properly.

Comment: It's not an exception, but a compiler error. You are missing the return statement in the "then" branch of your `if` at the bottom of the code. Suggestion: write `return sum % 10 == sum? sum : chkCM(sum);`

Comment: Aren't you using an IDE? Why is your code not formatted at all?

Answer (score 3):

you need to add a return statement to the recursive call to chkCM:

```
 if(sum%10!=sum)
    return chkCM(sum);
    else
    return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(sum%10!=sum)
    chkCM(sum);
```

To:

```
if(sum%10!=sum)
    return chkCM(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `chkCM(sum);` you should write `return chkCM(sum);`

The problem is, that the method will not return a value, if the if-clause (`if(sum%10!=sum)`) is true